# Identify hard brown "grass" in my yard

Tags: identification, lawn, grass

My dog is hesitant to walk on this crunchy, dead "grass". I didn't notice it much when the lawn was greener, but when this stuff started dying, it stays VERY rigid, and would be painful to walk on.

In North Texas, if it helps.

Bonus: Treatment ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what type of grass is your lawn made of?

Comment: Looks like something killed the lawn and now all you have is thatch.

Comment: Sadly, I don't even know what kind of grass this is. I've been hitting up this site to get all of this stuff figured out. =)

Comment: This question is currently too broad to answer. We need a closeup of the plant to distinguish identifying characteristics that cannot be seen currently.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to deal with engineering, not gardening.

Comment: @michelle Can you please suggest the appropriate place to ask such questions, or help me understand the disparity between engineering lawn and "landscaping"?

Comment: Personally, I was seeking some knowledgable advice, and this was the best place I thought I could find. ::shrug::

Comment: @anonymous coward, I cannot figure out how my comment ended up on your thread. I vaguely remember leaving that comment, but this isn't the post I remember looking at when I did! Apologies!